# Custom JSON converter for Noda Time

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, nodatime

I'm developing for .NET Core, so I'm using the unstable latest alpha of Noda Time (2.0.0-alpha20160729). Data is being handled with JSON.

I will be accepting user input for a date of birth field, and I want to support multiple input formats in case the user <s>can't follow directions</s> gets confused. For example, I want to accept both `MM-dd-yyyy` and `M/d/yy`, among others.

The [serialization docs](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/serialization.html) specifically state the following:

> Custom converters can be created easily from patterns using [NodaPatternConverter](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/T_NodaTime_Serialization_JsonNet_NodaPatternConverter_1.htm).

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this though. From what I understand, I will need to implement both `NodaPatternConverter<LocalDate>` itself, `IPattern<LocalDate>` for parsing, and `Action<T>` for validation.

I started writing `IPattern.Parse<LocalDate>`, but that function returns [`ParseResult<LocalDate>`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/T_NodaTime_Text_ParseResult_1.htm) which is apparently inaccessible. It cannot be instantiated or used in any way that I have found. I'm therefore stuck.

How do I properly create a custom JSON converter for Noda Time?

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, this doesn't sound like the right thing to do in a *JSON* converter. If you're accepting user input directly in your JSON, that should be treated as a string, and parsed later, IMO. JSON is a machine-to-machine format, not a human-to-machine format. Assuming this is a web app, you might want to use moment.js to parse the data at the client and reformat it as ISO-8601. Alternatively, deserialize it as a string and *then* convert it in your server-side code.

Anyway, for a JSON converter you only need to implement `IPattern<LocalDate>` - you don't need to *implement* `NodaPatternConverter<LocalDate>` as that already exists. You just need:

```
var pattern = ...;
var converter = new NodaPatternConverter<LocalDate>(pattern);
```

Now, to implement your pattern, you probably want to actually create it out of existing patterns - write an implementation which delegates to one `IPattern<LocalDate>` after another until the result is a `ParseResult<T>` which is successful - or return the final unsuccessful `ParseResult<T>`. Note that `ParseResult<T>` isn't inaccessible - but you can't (currently) create your own instance of it. That's something I should probably address, but in this case you don't really need to.

The code you need already exists but isn't exposed - you want the `Parse` part of [`CompositePattern`](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/Text/Patterns/CompositePattern.cs). To implement the `Format` part, you could just use the first of your patterns to format the value... if you even need to.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll test this out and report back. I thought a converter would be the best place to handle validation _and_ the conversion if successful, rather than having both a string and a `LocalDate` on my model and filling in the latter from the former. (That's a mess to do with Json.net too, trying to use one for serialization and the other for deserialization. But I digress.)